# Confirmation before every print-out on HP Color LaserJet 3550 / Windows Server

Tags: permissions, printing, printer, network-printer, hp-laserjet

A customer is experiencing this problem:

There is a HP Color LaserJet 3550 (usb-)connected to a HP Jetdirect 3700  network printing server.
The printing server is connected to a network switch.

Everytime they try to print out something from Remote-Desktop on Windows Server 2003 they have to confirm the print by pressing the green (✓) button on the LaserJet.
When they print from their local Desktop, they don't have to confirm anything - it just prints.

Here are some possible solutions I tried:

- checked the print-server settings
- replaced the print-server with a CUPS-Enabled Raspberry Pi (same problem)
- turned off the spooler on Server 2003 and redirected print jobs directly to the printer

I hope you can help me with this one,
cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the paper settings in the driver conflict with the settings on the printer.

The most likely culprit is the paper size. If the driver is set for Letter, and there is A4 paper in the printer (or vice versa) the printer will want you to confirm that it should go ahead with the different paper.

Another possibility is the paper type. That is also selected in the driver, but the printer can be told (via its web page or the front panel menu) what kind of paper is installed. Again, if driver and printer don't match you will be asked to press the GO button.

Yet another possibility is that you are trying to print from a tray that is not installed. In that case the printer will ask to print from the default tray.

Comment: That's a good approach.. However when printing some multi-page emails it prints out the first page, but wants confirmation for the second one.

Comment: It's possible that the pages have different paper settings. The most likely being that the first page is letterhead, the others are not.